# Pulling Google Drive into Command Line

Tags: python, google-sheets

Struggling to finish building out a python script intended to pull a few lines of text from 3 different columns in a Google spreadsheet.

When I run the script, I get the following error message:

```
  File "pr_email_robot.py", line 2, in <module>
    import gspread
ImportError: No module named gspread
Pats-MacBook-Pro:pr-email-robot-master patahern$
```

The area of code that must be off is:

```
import smtplib
import gspread

from gmail_variables import *

gc = gspread.login(GMAIL_USERNAME, GMAIL_PASSWORD)
wks = gc.open("PR-Command-Line-Emails").sheet1

recipients = wks.get_all_values()
```

I'm guessing that I have the wrong terminology to pull the Google Spreadsheet, but I can't find anything online about what to put in place of "gspread"

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Google Fusion Tables (still in beta)? You can query Google Fusion Tables' [Rest API](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/getting_started) using SQL syntax and `urllib`'s `urllib.request.urlopen()` to issue GET and POST requests. If you are heart set on using Google Sheets, the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/samples/reading) looks like it functions in much of the same way as Google Fusion Tables REST API. Meaning, you can still use the built in `urllib` Python library to issue GET and POST requests to the Sheets API.

It may also be helpful to note that Google has posted a [Getting Started in Python Guide for the Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/python). The example shown there, has no mention of any "gspread" imports.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have the gspread module installed somewhere your Python installation will find it.

If you have pip:
    pip install gspread

will make sure that it's installed.

**ALSO**

Gspread no longer supports using email/login for authentication, and relies on OAuth2 for authentication.

Check out how to set that up [here](http://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2.html).

Then check out the [gspread docs](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/master/README.md) for how to access info from your sheet!

Comment: Keliomer, this is extremely helpful! Thank you for your help! I will be honest though, I'm quickly realizing that I'm in way over my head trying to set this up on my own :)

Would you be open to helping me set this up as a small freelance project? I'll likely be needing to do this pretty frequently down the road for clients, and would love to find someone who truly understands python to help with this

Comment: I'd be happy to help, it's relatively straightforward to set this up and you'll (typically) only need to do it once per machine. Contact details are in my profile.